# SPServices : Write data into a list with UpdateListItems

Tags: list, form, spservices, updatelistitems

**Context** : I was trying to use UpdateListItems to write some html textbox data into a custom list. The list "Cabinet" contains 13 columns and has already a line of data, only the first column "name" is required.

**Problem** : My script can capture the form data, but can not update list, nothing appear in the list.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$("#send").click(function () {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var description = $("#description").val();

    CreateNewItem(name,description);
    return false;
}); });

function CreateNewItem(name, description) {
$().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    async: false,
    batchCmd: "New",
    listName: "Cabinet",
    valuepairs: [["name", name], ["description", description]],
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        window.status = status;
        window.alert(name+description);
        
    }
});}
```

When using SPDebugXMLHttpResult to catch the error, I got:

> ErrorCode 0x80004005
>
> ErrorText Cannot complete this action. Please try again.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42708/discussion-on-question-by-smyron-spservices-write-data-into-a-list-with-update).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like issue with the internal name, please confirm the column internal name.

try with may be "name" columns internal name, this can be default "Title"

valuepairs:[["Title",name], ["description", description]]

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a pretty nooby problem, I changed the display name of fields to static name and that works perfectly. 
Thanks for the community help and hope this answer could be helpful for the others.

Comment: You should accept Anuja's answer as correct, since he's the one who pointed out that you needed to use the internal name.